Does Cid realise Shadow Garden was completely serious about what they were doing?
In the first couple episodes, when the Seven Shadows tell Cid they’re going to leave to hunt the cult, he thinks they’ve finally realised that he made up the Cult of Diablos (even though he technically didn’t).
Later though, he fights with people claiming to be in the cult, and fights side-by-side with Shadow Garden again. However, he acts like he thinks they’re not following him anymore.
Did he realise they still follow him, or does he still think they’re playing along?

Bold of you to assume he thinks /s

I don't have the chapter on hand, but in some of the most recent chapters Cid still occasionally mentions in thoughts going along with my fantasies. Which would strike me as playing along
